# What is this Finder shortcut?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, uninstallation

A few days ago, my Samsung Galaxy S6 added a shortcut to "Finder" on my home screen.  I looked through my app list, and I can't find an app with that name.  What exactly is it, and how did it get added to my home screen?  If it's relevant, I'm in the US and use Sprint as my carrier.

The shortcut on my homescreen:

> [image: Picture of homescreen]

When the app runs:

> [image: Screenshot of app]

I haven't been able to find this in my app list.  What is this app, and if I want to uninstall it what do I need to do?

Comment: @beeshyams after digging around its help info it calls itself SFinder. That's too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by OP, it is [Sfinder](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00040909/) which is a Samsung app and cannot be uninstalled without root